# Form not redirecting

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

Could someone help me out? I've been trying to fix this thing for the past 2 hrs. It's probably some small mistake. Anyways when hitting the submit button the form (named: registration) won't work. I've tried login form redirection (which is hidden in this case) and it works, so it's not the server. It just stopped working suddenly, and I've been stepping back by few changes - nothing happens.

Here is my code anyways, thank you in advance.

First file :

```
<!--\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\          Membership Form       \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\    --->

    <div class="container-fluid even" id="membership_form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true">
      <div class="container">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2 class="text-center">Memberhip Form</h2>
        <div class="underline mx-auto rounded" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true"></div>
        <p class="text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true">Please fill out the following form to join the club!</p>
        <br>
        <form name="registration" action="registration.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name"><b>Name:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your first name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="surname"><b>Surname:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Please enter your surname" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address1"><b>Address Line 1:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" id="address1" placeholder="Enter adress line 1" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address2"><b>Address Line 2:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" id="address2" placeholder="Enter adress line 2" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address3"><b>Address Line 3:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address3" id="address3" placeholder="Enter adress line 3" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address4"><b>Address Line 4:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address4" id="address4" placeholder="Enter adress line 4">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eircode"><b>Eircode:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eircode" pattern="(D|d)[1-9](W|w)?\s?[A-Za-z]{2,}\d{2,}|(D|d)1[1-9]\s?[A-Za-z]{2,}\d{2,}|(D|d)2[0-4]\s?[A-Za-z]{2,}\d{2,}" id="eircode" placeholder="eg. D17AG45">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mobile"><b>Mobile:</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" pattern="\+\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|00\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|08\d-\d{3}-\d{4}|\+\d{10}|00\d{10}|08\d{8}" id="mobile" placeholder="eg: 0894576345" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob"><b>Date Of Birth:</b></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" required>
          </div>
          <br>
          <label for="gender_radio"><b>Gender:</b></label>
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="gender_radio" value="m" checked> Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender_radio" value="f"> Female
          </div>
          <br>
          <label for="membership_radio"><b>Membership:</b></label>
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="membership_radio" value="s" checked> Summer (€50/month)<br>
            <input type="radio" name="membership_radio" value="w"> Winter (€40/month)<br>
            <input type="radio" name="membership_radio" value="y"> Yearly (€30/month)<br>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="start_date"><b>Start Date:</b></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start_date" min="<?php echo date('Y\-m\-d');?>" required>
          </div>
          <br>
          <label for="family_radio"><b>Do you have a family member already registered:</b></label>
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="family_radio" value="true"> Yes</br>
            <input type="radio" name="family_radio" value="false" checked> No
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group" id="answer">
            <label for="family_head"><b>If you answered yes to the above question, please enter your family member's membership number:</b></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="family_head" id="family_head" placeholder="eg: 234531" required>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>

<!--\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\          Footer       \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\    --->

    <?php require_once('footer_n_scripts.php'); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Second file:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') header('Location: memberships.php#membership_form');
  else{
    require '../../db_connection_open.php';
    mysqli_select_db($db_connection, 'sintonidb');
  }

  function upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($str){
    $str = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach($str as $key => $value){
      $str[$key] = ucfirst($value);
    }
    $str = implode(' ', $str);
    $str = explode('-', $str);
    foreach($str as $key => $value){
      $str[$key] = ucfirst($value);
    }
    $str = implode('-', $str);

    return $str;
  }
?>
```

```
<!--\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\          Registration       \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\    --->

    <div class="container-fluid even" id="membership_form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true">
      <div class="container">
        <?php
          $errors = array();

          foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $_POST[$key] = trim($value);
            $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($value);
            $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($value);
          }

          if(empty($_POST['name'])) $errors[] = 'Name is required';
          else{
            $_POST['name'] = upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($_POST['name']);
          }

          if(empty($_POST['surname'])) $errors[] = 'Surname is required';
          else{
            $_POST['surname'] = upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($_POST['surname']);
          }

          if(empty($_POST['email'])) $errors[] = 'Email is required.';
          else{
            if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
              $errors[] = 'Email address is not valid.';
            }
          }

          if(empty($_POST['address1']) || empty($_POST['address2']) || empty($_POST['address3'])) $errors[] = 'Address line 1-3 is required.';
          else{
            $address = upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($_POST['address1']) . ',\n' . upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($_POST['address2']) . ',\n' .upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($_POST['address3']);
            if(isset($_POST['address4'])) $address .= ',\n' . upper_case_by_space_n_hyphen($_POST['address4']);
          }

          /*if(empty($_POST['eircode'])) $errors[] = 'Eircode is required.';
          else{
            $_POST['eircode'] = toUpperCase($_POST['eircode']);
          }

          if(empty($_POST['mobile'])) $errors[] = 'Mobile is required.';
          else{
            //if(!preg_match('\+\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|00\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|08\d-\d{3}-\d{4}|\+\d{10}|00\d{10}|08\d{8}', $_POST['mobile'])) $errors[] = 'Mobile format is invalid.';
          }*/


          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($_POST);
          echo '</br>' . $address . '</br>';
          //print_r($errors);
          echo '</pre>';
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] -  FAR too much code here. Enable PHP error messages and look in the console

Comment: but I don't know whats relevant

Comment: here I hope I didn't delete sth relevant

Comment: What you just deleted certainly was not. Thanks

Comment: Console errors? PHP Errors?

Comment: nope, nothing. it won't even redirect to the second file and the first one checks out

Comment: Don't you need a die here: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')  { header('Location: memberships.php#membership_form'); die(); }`

Comment: And what if you just have `echo '<pre>';
          print_r($_POST);
          echo '</pre>';`

Comment: nope it doesn't make a difference because it is most likely the membership.php (first file) where the error is, because it won't even redirect to registration.php (second file)

Answer (score 0):

Found an error, last input was hidden and also required.

Comment: Hidden input fields do not accept `required` attribute, so that cannot  prevent the form from working properly.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain properly, it was hidden with jQuery (by fadeOut method) not with attribute hidden in html.